# Driving Smart LEDs (integrated IC) at 24V

Tags: led, datasheet, led-driver, rgb

I need the help of someone more competent at deciphering datasheets of obscure components. I am currently building an LED indoor light installation and would like to have hundreds (400-800) of individually addressable LEDs. The most straight forward solution would be to use the common WS2812 RGB LEDs, that however would entail using copper wires as thick as garden hoses to distribute the 5V power. I know there are also 12V LEDs out there, but 24V would be much better. After several weekend nights of research I have finally found a smart LED that might be up to the task and is pretty affordable at the same time, while not drawing incredible amounts of power doing nothing:

IN-PI55TBTPRPGPB from Inolux ([Datasheet](https://www.mouser.de/datasheet/2/180/IN-PI55TBT(X)R(X)G(X)B_v1.3-1667463.pdf))

Now the datasheet is fairly readable to me, but I am missing some critical information here. On page 4 there is a property that is named as "R/G/B port pressure - VDS,MAX" and it states 24V. Does that mean I might be able to attach VCC to a 24V rail? The ratings for VCC are not mentioned anywhere.
Every piece of advice is appreciated!

Comment: I dont think that means what you want. Have you considered localizing a voltage regulator?

Comment: @Passerby do you mean like a linear regulator at each segment or each LED? Both of these options sound liker they are wasting a lot of energy to me.

Comment: @user263983 As stated in the question, I am aware of that component, but it is not what I want, since I would like to use my 24V power supply.

Comment: No, you can not supply 24V to 5V chip. And that parameter, you mention, manufacturer should be asked for definition. It may be a bad translation from  Chinese.

Comment: More like a switching regulator for x number of segments.

Comment: @Passerby That does seem like a sensible idea. It would drive up the cost of the installation by quite a bit though and at the same time the regulators would have to be fairly small to fit. Do you have a recommendation for shallow pockets?

Comment: @d.oelert smaller pockets simply mean you do to the buck regulator table of your favorite distributor and buy what they're currently kicking from their stock at a discount. But even when buying a regularly priced buck regulator IC, inductor and external transistor, for a couple hundred LEDs, this does really not drive up project cost all that much.

Comment: I remember when Jumbotrons were $3million bucks (that's a lot of regulators;). now with cost reductions you still need to boost your budget and power due to inefficiencies with 100mW /LED * 3 *  800 = >> 240W min supply.  So how much can you afford? for all then we can have a good laff . also how big? Bigger than OLED TV?

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 With LEDs that draw 12mA per channel, I would use roughly 450. These would take 80W (not accounting for inefficiencies) when all channels at full output, which is not the intended use case, since I've already incorporated 2700K and 5700K LEDs with a balance of CRI vs lm/W skewed towards the efficacy side. Both of these channels with 224 LEDs each should draw around 25W, respectively. Keep in mind, this is also at full power (roughly 3000lm). The RGB LEDs are more of an addon here. Also not a jumbotron, but a ceiling light. :)

Comment: Why do You want 450x3 addressable LEDs ? Disco? Area? Budget? 3k lm is as much as one 4 ft 32W tri phosphor FL tube

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Kind of an art installation, although I'd call it more of a proof of concept. The area is pretty small with 3.5mx3.5m, just a room for testing. Budget is close to nonexistent, since it is not really a commercial thing. Also, yes that is true, however so far I have managed to drive it down in cost so drastically, that the improvement of the light quality is worth paying a few € more for dual white LEDs, to ditch the fluorescent tubes. We are really far from the point here, though.

Comment: to save money LM2956HV modules from aliexpress.  run 48V DC power to the buck modules  each module is good for about 1A continuous, or 3A peak. (output current) just apply power to the strip every few meters.

Comment: Especially for a permanent installation, it's always worth considering plumpening your wires.  Make sure you check the prices of common types of larger size wire and if you know someone who is redoing their basement you may be able to get some old dirty wire that is otherwise fine for free.  It should be FT4 rated.  There are a lot of advantages to using a larger number of isolated voltage converters for your application with the main concern being accessibility (So far your application sounds like indirect lighting from a ceiling bulkhead or somesuch?)

Comment: One note about using regulator modules found on aliexpress is that if you cause a fire, your insurance may be void as these devices usually lack the seal of an appropriate regulator body like UL (Underwriter's Labs) or CSA (Canadian Standards Association) in Canada.  They may also not be intended to be installed bare in a building, so you may want to put (or mount) them in electrical boxes.  Are they strips or single LEDs?  What distance between them?  Are they on MCPCBs (Metal circuit board, usually aluminum)?  I can give you some advice to figure out your wire sizes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "R/G/B port pressure - VDS,MAX" and it states 24V. {actually 26V}
> Does that mean I might be able to attach VCC to a 24V rail?

NO, That is the maximum Vds of the internal FET with open circuit programmed to draw  no current or very little , otherwise meltdown.

You must use 4.5 to 5.5V.

Addition info

36mA max per chip x 5V = 180 mW needs ventilation on both sides or a 3 cm^2 copper substrate, so you may as well get the RGB string and cut into sections and use 48V power to distribute to 5.5v dropping to 4.5V at the end using the LM2956HV PCB’s from Banggood or the 24V to 5V 3A regulators $15cdn/10pc each driving 3A/36mA= Say <80 chips.

Comment: I like your additional info. What struck me is that one sees such light installations on occasion, but I never recall seeing a wire "as thick as garden hoses" . Of course if you don't want to build anything but the light string .. maybe such complexities are unwanted

Comment: I have seen conductors of solid copper as thick as an elephant trunk in my 1st job. So I  injected  100A and chose a 1ft space or so to get 10 mV or something , put in 2 self-tapping screws and called it a Kelvin shunt ! and monitored up to 100kA into a fusion diffusion bonder with around 4V Nom. Water jets for cooling to make nuclear cooling tubes bonded with a Zirconium shim. 

Although 1/2” copper water pipes make a nice cheap fixture for conducting high power with low voltage. Plus there no skin effect with DC. And if things get really crazy there’s always a water cooling option.

Answer (score 1):

This is a 5V chip, it won't do what you want.

There are 12V "individually" addressable LED strips that are more efficient, **BUT** to get to 12V the LEDs are clustered in series strings of 3, so you can't control each LED, only each group of 3 LEDs. If this is okay, then go for it.

There are real 12V individually addressable LED strips where the RGB LEDs are wired in series inside the LEd package. So the chip uses only one current source, which means it uses 3x less current as WS2812B. If you choose white light, it is more efficient. However if you use only one color, then it is less efficient. Since you got separate white LEDs, I guess you won't be using the RGBs for white, so this would not work.

Basically you're going to need a lot of 5V current.

Don't use LM2596 modules from aliexpress. They're all counterfeit chips, with garbage high-ESR capacitors that will overheat and die.

If you to a 4mx3m matrix, then you can power the strips from a beefy 4m long power bus in the middle, and each strip will only be 1.5m long.

However for transportation it will be more convenient to split the panel in smaller chunks. Say four rectangles of 1.5x2m. Or even more chunks, maybe 8 rectangles, so it can be transported easily in a car. Put a 5V power supply on each in the center, with an offset so you can stack the rectangles back to back for transportation, and a 5V bus running in the middle of each rectangle, connected to the center of each strip. It's better to power them from the center rather than from one end, since that cuts voltage drop along the strip in half.

This way voltage drop will be quite low in the short half-strips, and maybe you can tweak the pot on the 5V power supply to decrease voltage a bit. Since the LED chips use current sources, they'll still work on a bit less than 5V, and dissipate less heat.

Several lower power 5V supplies could very well be less costly than a big one, and the low power ones won't need fans.

You will also need 24V power supplies for your white LEDs though. But that's much easier, you won't need one per rectangle.